# Flutter Youtube Video Upload

Tags: flutter, dart, video, youtube

I would like to know if there is any method or api to upload videos to youtube directly from my flutter application? One way would be to use webview, but it's not so comfortable and user-friendly. Thank You very much for any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Use `googleapis` Youtube Data:

- [API Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/youtube.v3/youtube.v3-library.html)
- [Example from official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/google-apis)

#### My Upload Snippet:

```
static Future<Video> upload() async {
  var youTubeApi = await getYoutubeApi();

  File f = File('assets/sample-mp4-file-small.mp4');
  Stream<List<int>> stream = f.openRead();
  Media m = Media(stream, (await f.length()));
  Video video = Video(
    snippet: VideoSnippet(
      title: 'Pong Map Test Video',
      description: 'Test Upload for Pong Map app',
      categoryId: '22',
    ),
  );

  return await youTubeApi.videos.insert(
    video,
    ['snippet', 'status'],
    uploadMedia: m,
  );
}
```

#### My Full example with Auth

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth.dart';
import 'package:shared/services/toast_utility.dart';

class YoutubeService {
  static Future<YouTubeApi> getYoutubeApi() async {
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: <String>[
        YouTubeApi.youtubeReadonlyScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeUploadScope
      ],
    );
    await googleSignIn.signIn();

    // final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    var httpClient = await googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();
    if (httpClient == null) {
      print("You didn't allow to proceed with YouTube access");
    }

    return YouTubeApi(httpClient!);
  }

  static Future<VideoListResponse> listYoutubePlaylists() async {
    var youTubeApi = await getYoutubeApi();
    var data = await youTubeApi.videos.list(
      ['snippet'],
      chart: "mostPopular",
    );
    return data;
  }

  static Future<Video> upload() async {
    var youTubeApi = await getYoutubeApi();

    File f = File('assets/sample-mp4-file-small.mp4');
    Stream<List<int>> stream = f.openRead();
    Media m = Media(stream, (await f.length()));
    Video video = Video(
      snippet: VideoSnippet(
        title: 'Test Video',
        description: 'Test Upload for My App',
        categoryId: '22',
      ),
    );

    return await youTubeApi.videos.insert(
      video,
      ['snippet', 'status'],
      uploadMedia: m,
    );
  }
}
```

Note that you do need `extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth` and `google_sign_in` both in your `pubspec.yaml` for authorization. And of course the `googleapis` package.

Answer (score 2):

Google provides API tools for YouTube. You can learn more [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).

Furthermore, there is a package that implements that same api in a more friendly way, as shown [here](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_api).

Comment: This package doesn't include the upload functionality yet.

Comment: @JanF. Then I'm afraid there you will have to deep dive into the YouTube API page. And even then, I don't know if they support uploading. That is your objective, go for it :D.